# How can I run a command in an open terminal window using Cuttlefish?

Tags: cuttlefish

I would like to configure Cuttlefish to open an open terminal window running the command `unison -batch` when I connect my external hard drive.

However, I cannot seem to find the right configuration on the below screen to actually open a terminal window.

[image]

Comment: You want this to be achieved specifically with Cuttlefish ?are alternatives welcome ?

Comment: I would prefer Cuttlefish. What alternatives are there?